# Cannot insert caret and backtick in XTerm

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xterm

I cannot insert carets and backticks (and possibly other characters) in XTerm under certain conditions. When I move focus from XTerm to Firefox and use Alt+Tab to switch back, I can no longer instert ^ and `.

Strangely enough, I can only reproduce the problem by Alt+Tabbing from Firefox to XTerm, other applications don't seem to cause the issue. From what I've tried, it really is the act of tabbing *into* the XTerm, tabbing to Firefox and clicking back works just normally.

I am running XTerm(297) on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I'm using a German keyboard layout, so I have to follow carets and backticks by a space to make them appear alone. With this issue, pressing the backtick/caret key does simply nothing at all, and the following space inserts a space. When I use a US keyboard layout for testing, everything works fine too.

Please help me solve this mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess: the Alt+Tab back to xterm does not really place the focus inside the VT100 window.

Even one pixel off can produce a problem when you have composed keys, e.g., between scrollbar and the VT100 window.

`xterm` adds key-translations to allow you to type "anywhere" on its overall window, but the XIM code does not allow multiple windows to act as *its* input.  There have been a couple of bug-reports related to moving the cursor across that gap.  A related issue was reported in *[Debian Bug report logs - #721523 xterm: XIM preview position incorrect](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=721523)*

(There is no easy fix for this scenario).